# Python peewee foreign keys

Tags: python, foreign-keys, peewee

If I have the following table:

```
class Ticket(BaseModel):
    event = ForeignKeyField(Event)
    category = ForeignKeyField(TicketCategory)
    order_number = IntegerField()
    tier_name = CharField()
    num_available = IntegerField()
   price = DecimalField()
```

Then I execute the following code:

```
tickets = Ticket.select()
for ticket in tickets:

     print ticket.event.id
```

Does accessing the primary key of the foreign object force peewee to launch another query? Or is peewee smart enough to know that the id is already available?

Comment: you could check out the source, or step through the code using `pdb`.  In django each foreignkey has a field in the table called `<<field_name>>_id` which doesn't trigger a foreignkey lookup.  If you were usin gjdnaog `ticket.event_id` wouldn't trigger the lookup, but i'm assuming `ticket.event.id` does, check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It executes another query. To avoid this:

```
Ticket.select(Ticket, Event).join(Event)
```

http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#saving-queries-by-selecting-related-models

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that particular solution; however, in this situation, I don't need to access the entire event object. Is there no way to lazily just grab the event_id from the ticket object?

Comment: Use ``ticket._data['event']``

Comment: ok i guess that works...is it possible to introduce a lazy load of the id by directly accessing ticket.event_id in the future? So basically if ever someone access:

object.<foreign_key>_id

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "lazy load of the id". The ID is loaded as part of the query, i.e. Ticket.select() will select the event_id column. Peewee, since it is an ORM, exposes this as a related object. If you want the ID, you can access that from the raw table data, stored in `model_instance._data`.  If you want, you could write a property on your model and expose the event_id that way.

Comment: Ok, I simply meant i'd like to be able to access it using model_instance.event_id.

So I can have event listed as a foreign key, and event_id listed as an IntegerField() and it will work fine?

Comment: No, that will be confusing to the ORM. Just implement a property, i.e. def event_id(self): --- return self._data['event']

Comment: Per tddawson's answer below you can now do <field_name>_id to access the id.

Furthermore, you can also use the lazy_load argument in ForeignKeyField to do as Atul Bhatia asked (i.e. only load the ID without loading the entire object via query). See http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#foreignkeyfield

Answer (score 9):

It's a few years later, but for anyone else who stumbles across this page, these days you can use the same syntax that Django uses: <<field_name>>_id to access the id. In this case, ticket.event_id.

Per the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#foreignkeyfield):

> Sometimes you only need the associated primary key value from the foreign key column. In this case, Peewee follows the convention established by Django, of allowing you to access the raw foreign key value by appending "_id" to the foreign key field’s name:

It is, however, worth noting that this only works when accessing the value of a queried object. In other words, if you wanted to change the event id, just set

> ticket.event = new_event_id

instead of trying to set ticket.event_id.

The same holds true when trying to select based off a foreign key:

> Ticket.select().where(event == desired_event_id)

Comment: exactly what I'm trying to know when I hit this page.

Comment: FYI you can also use the lazy_load argument in ForeignKeyField to make the field behave like an ID (i.e. only load the ID without loading the entire object via query). See http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#foreignkeyfield